# Stubbing logged in user (current_user) with rspec - how to make it work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

In my users_controller_spec.rb I put

```
@u = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
ApplicationController.should_receive(:current_user).at_least(:once).and_return(@u)
controller.stub :current_user => @u
```

and then I want to write controller specs that show me if a object is indeed inaccesible for the users that should not see it - there exits a `require_ownership` function in the application_controller.rb which uses the var `@current_user` to see who's logged in, but with the method above I cannot find to make the user "logged in".

Comment: what kind of specs? controller?

Comment: yes, controller_specs.. For example the test "1) log in 2) `get :edit` 3) can access it", or "1) don't log in 2) get :edit, 3) cannot access it"

Comment: What exactly is your line 2 supposed to achieve? Only the `controller.stub` should be enough to stub out `@u` as the logged in user.

Comment: it's based on authlogic (There is a UserSession model that inherits from there). It's working if I do `UserSession.create(@u)`.. But maybe this is not the perfect solution, because then the test is slower due to database use

Comment: `controller.stub :current_user => @u
` should be enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working if I do UserSession.create(@u) - and this is fine for me.